# Python pandas: determining which "group" has the most entries

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say that I have pandas DataFrame with a column called "fruit" that represents what fruit my classroom of kindergartners had for a morning snack. I have 20 students in my class. Breakdown would be something like this.

Oranges = 7, Grapes = 3, Blackberries = 4, Bananas = 6

I used sort to group each of these fruit types, but it is grouping based on alphabetical order. I would like it to group based on the largest quantity of entries for that class of fruit. In this case, I would like Oranges to turn up  first so that I can easily see that Oranges is the most popular fruit.

I'm thinking that sort is not the best way to go about this. I checked out groupby but could not figure out how to use that appropriately either.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

To sort by name: `df.fruit.value_counts().sort_index()`

To sort by counts: `df.fruit.value_counts().sort_values()`

Comment: I did this as recommended: df.fruit.value_counts().sort_index()

I was given a result like this, which discovered is a Series:
Oranges    5    
Bananas   13
Apples     2

I want to return "Bananas" in the function that I created because Bananas has the highest count at 13, I am puzzled as to how to do this. If it was a data frame, my thought was I could  sort by the integer column and then return the first string in the fruit-based column.

I'm new to pandas and Python, I'm not quite sure how to convert the Series to a Data frame the way I mentioned  or if that's even necessary?

Answer (score 0):

In Pandas 0.17:

```
df.sort_values(by='fruit', ascending=False)
```